# Bash Script to move files to a folder that are named after the file

Tags: macos, bash, sed, scripting, terminal

Fairly new to scripting.
Im trying to do the following.
I have a folder that contains:

```
/folder/Tv Series Name S01E01 - Episode Name A.avi  
/folder/Tv Series Name S01E02 - Episode Name B.avi  
/folder/Tv Series Name S01E03 - Episode Name C.avi  
/folder/Tv Series Name S01E04 - Episode Name D.avi  
/folder/Tv Series Name S01E05 - Episode Name E.avi
```

I want to create a folder and move the file to it's specific folder:

```
/folder/Tv Series Name S01E01/Tv Series Name S01E01 - Episode Name A.avi  
/folder/Tv Series Name S01E02/Tv Series Name S01E02 - Episode Name B.avi  
/folder/Tv Series Name S01E03/Tv Series Name S01E03 - Episode Name C.avi  
/folder/Tv Series Name S01E04/Tv Series Name S01E04 - Episode Name D.avi  
/folder/Tv Series Name S01E05/Tv Series Name S01E05 - Episode Name E.avi
```

I have tried:

```
cd ...Path/folder
ls -1 |
while read filename 
do
newPath=`echo $filename|sed "s/-[^-]*$//"`
mv $filename ...Path/folder/$newPath/$filename
done
```

I manage to get the name I want, but I could not create/move to folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes are wrong. You should basically always use double quotes around variables with file names (and most of the time in other cases as well).

In addition, you should not parse `ls` output, and use a `for` loop instead, idiomatically.

Finally, it is more efficient to use the shell's built-in string substitutions rather than two external processes.

```
cd .../Path/to/folder
for filename in *; do
    newPath=${filename%\ -*}
    mkdir -p "$newPath"
    mv "$filename" "$newPath"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do, with the example you provided:

```
for file in *.avi; do
    dir=${file%% -*}
    echo mkdir -p -- "$dir"
    echo mv "$file" "$dir"
done
```

Oh, this will not do anything, only echo the commands that will be executed. Remove the two `echo`s if you're happy with what you see. (execute it from within `/folder`).

Answer (score 1):

I just used this but made the following change:

```
dir=${file%% -*}
```

to

```
dir=${file%%.*}
```

Because I was getting folders with the file extension still in the name.
The above change removes that.
Thank you!

Pasted below for convienience

```
for file in *.mpg; do
    dir=${file%%.*}
    echo mkdir -p -- "$dir"
    echo mv "$file" "$dir"
done
```

Just replace .mpg with the type of file you are looking for.

EDIT:
Important!
Make sure your file names don't contain any "."
The above creates the folder name up to the first "." it finds in the file name.